# WebView2 | CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEvent Error

Tags: c, webview2

I need help when i`m starting the webbrowser then i getting this error, i dont know why is it null

```
        CoreWebView2 WebView2;

        public TabViewItem CurrentTab;

        public TabContent()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Browser.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += DownloadStarting_Event;

        }
        private void DownloadStarting_Event(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This is a test");
        }
```

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not totally clear from the code you have shared, but it doesn't look like you are waiting for the WebView2 element to initialize its CoreWebView2 property before using the CoreWebView2 property. This is described in detail in the [WebView2 reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1518.46).

In brief, you must await a successful call to `WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` or wait until the `WebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event is raised successfully before using the `WebView2.CoreWebView2` property.